# How to name an address validation api based on the naming standards

Tags: rest, restful-url

I have created an api which fetches address information from the user and sends it here maps api to get the corresponding timezone and lat,long information.
My aim is to verify whether the address has corresponding lat,long information or not.
If there is no information for that address here maps would fail and i would generate a 404 error for that address.
Basically I am trying to create a address validation api which returns success if address is correct and 404 for incorrect address.

POST - api/v1/timezone-address/validate
Is this api naming correct or can I improve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include the version number it is considered to be good practice and plus check out this doc which I found helpful when I needed
Follow this link https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/naming_convention